# Show that $\sqrt{x}$ is continuous using sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, continuity

> Show that $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ using the sequence definition.

The sequence definition is referring to $f$ being continuous in a point $x$ if for all sequences $(x_n)_n$ with $x_n\to x$ it holds that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=f(x)$.

In this case $f$ is continuous for all $(0,\infty)$ because we can pick any non-negative sequence $(x_n)_n$ with $x_n\to x\geq 0$ then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}|\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{x}|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|x_n-x|}{\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt{x}} \overset{(*)}{\leq}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|x_n-x|}{\sqrt{x}}=0.$$

For $x=0$ we can pick any $(x_n)_n$ with $x_n\to 0$ thus $(\sqrt{x_n})_n\to 0$ as well, hence $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$.

I am curious if the estimation marked with $(*)$ is really necessary and if yes, why so? It felt logical to do so, yet I can't explain the reasoning to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can circumvent that estimation with

$$|\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{x}|^2 = |\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{x}||\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{x}|\leqslant |\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{x}||\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt{x}|=|x_n - x|.$$

Hence, for any $\epsilon >0$ there exists $N \in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n > N$ we have $|x_n - x| < \epsilon^2$ and

$$0 \leqslant |\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{x}| \leqslant |x_n-x|^{1/2} < \epsilon$$

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's really necessary, but it's a valid estimation, it is not too rough (i.e. the argument still works after doing the estimation), and (perhaps most importantly) it becomes a lot easier to evaluate the limit in the end (using, for instance, the squeeze theorem). Therefore I would personally deem it a good step to make.